# I'm trying to use mistic100/jQuery.extendext to generate a UI for dynamic queries but keep getting on on odd error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I load the required scripts as below and try to load my blade view in Laravel, PHP. However, I get the following error

Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' jquery-extendext.js:7

It turns out that the JS file contains some HTML, I do not understand how it has been successfully used in other projects.

```
    @extends('layouts.master')

    @section('content')

        <!-- Your previous content remains unchanged -->
    
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h4 class="c-grey-900 mB-20">{{$pageTitle}}</h4>
                <a href="{{ route('pam-reports.index') }}" class="btn btn-success btn-color pull-             right">Back</a>
                <br><br>


    
            @foreach($columns as $column)
                {{ ucfirst(str_replace('_', ' ', $column)) }}
            @endforeach
        
    
    <!-- No need to populate the tbody here, DataTables will handle it -->

            
        
    


    @endsection

    @section('scripts')


    var columnsFromController = @json($columns);
    console.log(columnsFromController);

    // the default rules, what will be used on page loads...
    var datatablesRequest = {};
    var \_rules = defaultRules = {
        "condition": "AND",
        "rules": \[{
            "id": "status",
            "field": "status",
            "type": "string",
            "input": "radio",
            "operator": "equal",
            "value": "A"
        }
    
    
    
    \]
    };

    // a button/link that is used to update the rules.
    function updateFilters() {
        \_rules = $('#querybuilder').queryBuilder('getRules');
        reloadDatatables();
    }

    function filterChange() {
        var \_json = JSON.stringify(\_rules);
        datatablesRequest = {
            rules: \_json
        };
    }

    filterChange();

    function reloadDatatables() {
        /\* Datatables first... \*/
        filterChange();

        $('.dataTable').each(function() {
            dt = $(this).dataTable();
            dt.fnDraw();
        })
    }

    var dtColumns = columnsFromController.map(function(col) {
    return { data: col, name: col };
    });

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    
    // dynamic table
    oTable = jQuery('#dataTable').dataTable({
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {
            url: '{{ route('pam-reports.earns-dedus') }}',
            data: function(d) {
                $.extend(d, datatablesRequest);
                // Add your custom parameters directly here, if you have any.
            }
        },
        columns: dtColumns
    });


    //     $('#builder').queryBuilder({
    //     filters: \[
    //         { id: 'id', label: 'ID', type: 'integer' },
    //         { id: 'dedu_def_id', label: 'Deduction Definition ID', type: 'integer' },
    //         { id: 'dedu_def_code', label: 'Deduction Definition Code', type: 'string' },
    //         { id: 'emp_id', label: 'Employee ID', type: 'integer' },
    //         { id: 'status', label: 'Status', type: 'string' },
    //         { id: 'created_at', label: 'Created At', type: 'date', validation: { format: 'YYYY-    MM-DD' } },
    //         { id: 'updated_at', label: 'Updated At', type: 'date', validation: { format: 'YYYY-MM-DD' } }
    //     \]
    // });
    console.log($('#builder').length);

    $('#builder').queryBuilder();
    });




    @endsection
```

I tried changing the order in which I'm loading the dependencies and it appears that the current order is OK.

Comment: "_It turns out that the JS file contains some HTML_" Where exactly? https://github.com/mistic100/jQuery.extendext/blob/master/jquery-extendext.js

Comment: Within the entire file. Am I perhaps using it wrong? I simply imported into and each load throws an exception.

Comment: Oh wait, thanks. I was downloading the wrong file.

Comment: We don't know which file you imported or how you imported it. I linked to `jquery-extendext.js` in my first comment and there seems to be no HTML in that file

Comment: I had downloaded the file on this page https://github.com/mistic100/jQuery.extendext